# Wordpress issue with php 7

Tags: wordpress, php-7

I'm trying to install WordPress on host with PHP version 7 but WordPress style and scripts seems not work properly and WP themes ruined ( even in WP installation steps ) . 
It works fine on PHP 5.6 
[image]

here's my server information :
 
PHP : 7.1.0
Apache : 2.2.29
MySQL Version : 5.5.52-cll

Comment: If you had Google'd that error, you would've seen others reporting this as bugs to Wordpress. Besides, you don't actually have any question you've asked.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress 4.6 isn't compatible with PHP 7.1 but WordPress 4.7 will be.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37772

Comment: Thanks it works . and php7 just like they said is very faster than php 5.6